# Point traefik ingress at different paths with different services under the same host in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik

I have separate services that point to separate services within my cluster. I have a singular ingress set up, that points to a url, with 3 path objects,  /, /path1, and path2. All 3 paths point at separate services. However, when I go to any path, it automatically points to the service from /. I have tried rewrite target, which doesn't seem to make much of a difference. Is there something else I need to do to fix this?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: X-Forwarded-User, X-Auth-User, X-Secret
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: forward
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: http://traefik-forward-auth-svc.ingress.svc.cluster.local:4181
  name: ingress1
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myurl.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /path1
      - backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
        path: /path2
```

```
Name:              service1
Namespace:         dev
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=deployment1
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                *ip here*
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.159.95:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>


Name:              service2
Namespace:         dev
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=deployment2
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                *ip here*
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.134.76:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: share the full ingress yaml

Comment: so if you hit myurl.com/path1 or myurl.com/path2 it goes to service?

Comment: It seems that way. The webpage it returns is the one that is rendered from a container that is deployed via a kubernetes deployment, and exposed through service.

Comment: Can you share output if kubectl describe svc service, service1,service2

Comment: what annotation you used for rewrite target?

Comment: I've tried both the regular  kubernetes ingress one and the traefik one ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

Comment: try this annotation is not done already traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefixStrip

Comment: I have also tried this one to no avail :(

Comment: Its cloud, local, virtual (virtual box) environment? How did you deploy Traefik Ingress? From docs, helm?